# PHP segfault when spread operator is applied to object

Tags: php, segmentation-fault, php-7.1

FINAL EDIT :: Look at answer

---

okay, given this snippet of code

```
private function select(string $key, string ...$keys): Model
{
    \array_unshift($keys, $key);

    foreach($keys as &$key)
    {
        $key = \preg_replace_callback('/([a-zA-Z]+)\((.*)\)/', function($match){
        return \sprintf('%s(%s)', $match[1], $this->primaryFields()->keys()->first());
    }, $key);
}
```

the line where the key is written segfaults in this case, at first I thought this was because some weird stuff happened with Prce. However when I set it with a string literal the same happens. In the end I solved this problem with commenting out the `array_unshift`. I could in a sense create a new array which 'unshifts' the `$key` argument, but thus shouldn't be necessary I think, does anyone know if this is a PHP quirk, or did I misunderstand something here?

btw I'm running php7.1 as fpm

---

EDIT ::

Okay, I was writing a whole story of what I am developing, But I seem to have pinpointed the cause, it is an `sprintf` specifically this block

```
$keys = \array_map(function($key){
    $matches = Regex::match('/([a-zA-Z]+)\((.*)\)/', $key);

    $string = \key_exists(2, $matches)
        ? $matches[2]
        : $key;

    if(\count($matches) > 0)
    {
        $format = \sprintf('%s(%%s.`%%s`)', $matches[1]);
    }
    else
    {
        $format = $string === '*'
            ? '%s.%s'
            : '%s.`%s`';
    }

    return \sprintf($format, $this->owner->getTarget(), $string);
}, $this->keys);
```

the `sprintf` on the last line of the callback is what segfaults, when and only when the format is created by the if, when it goes through the else is works fine.

I the way I create my format not allowed? is does create a valid format for as far as I know "'count(%s.`%s`)", some more testing shows me that when I change the `$format` assignment in the if to `$format = '%s.`%s`'` I still get a segfault.

The most weird thing is, yesterday when I did the pin-pointing I got all the... Whilst typing this php seems to have decided that this code is proper now.. What I was trying to say that yesterday it didn't segfault until within zf3 the `new PDO` was called...

I am truly lost as of where to look...

Comment: If it segfaults, you can be 100% sure that PHP itself has failed and you've uncovered a bug. *However*, your code is very ambiguous too (hint: `$key` both in and out of the loop) and you shouldn't write it like that either.

Comment: cannot reproduce: https://3v4l.org/gpIV9 - can you provide a reproducible test case?

Comment: Anything in the PHP error log?

Comment: Can you take a snapshot of the data you're passing in, and try making a standalone reproducible test case. There's a good chance that that will be hard to do, as it's likely to be a bug elsewhere, that just happens to be causing the problem here. :-/

Comment: @Narf I thought the same and did some playing around, however that didn't solce anything as the `$key` is just overriden

@Gordon I think it would be to big, we're talking custom ORM big

@JesseSchokker Nope, first place where I looked, any log on the server related to webrequests are clean of errors

@Danack Not sure if I can this is build on top of zend framework 3

Comment: Please run php using "USE_ZEND_ALLOC=0 valgrind php script.php your-args" and post the resulting log somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, long story short, it had nothing to do with regex or array shifts. Turns out that the `...`(spread) operator applied to an object that has ArrayAccess, IteratorAggregate etc, everything that makes that object work as an array, randomly seems to segfault when called with the `...` operator.

---

i.e. given this class signature we are capable to handle this class as if it were an array(there are no implementation details here to save space in the explanation)

```
class Foo implements \ArrayAccess, \IteratorAggregate
{
    public function getIterator()

    public function offsetExists($offset)
    public function offsetGet($offset)
    public function offsetSet($offset, $value)
    public function offsetUnset($offset)
}

$foo = new Foo;
$foo[] = 'one';
$foo[] = 'two';
$foo[] = 'three';
```

Okay, lets agree that `$foo` contains the tree added items. if `$foo` were to be an `array` we could do `function(...$foo)` which would result in a function call `function('one', 'two', 'three')`. right? alright then, when I did this in my code with my `Collection` class(my `Foo` in a sense) it would segfault(not always, just with certain instances, and no; there were no keys defined, I tested that, and as well as with an array it would give an error "can't unpack array with keys").

---

I still have no clue why it segfault just that my workaround is to cast my `Collection` to an `array`. Neither do I know if this is a know bug at PHP nor how to really search for it.

---

TL;DR :: when using the `...` operator to unpack make sure the thing you try to unpack is an `array` ;)

Comment: For those curious, we tested the codebase in PHP7.2RC6 today and the segfault persisted

Comment: If you have found a reproducible crash, please report it on bugs.php.net. PHP is not supposed to segfault.

Comment: @Andrea this was indeed a bug and I've reported it, this fix is shipped with PHP7.2.2